# Updating conda environment from file offline

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am successfully creating a Conda environment from the `environment.yml` file. The problem is when I decide to add a new dependency on the environment and I want to update it offline. I modified the `environment.yml` file and tried this:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

But the result is:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages
cffi-1.14.2          | 227 KB    | ################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
setuptools-49.6.0    | 748 KB    | ################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
cryptography-3.0     | 573 KB    | ################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
pip-20.2.2           | 1.7 MB    | ################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
selenium-3.141.0     | 820 KB    | ################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
python-3.8.5         | 49.3 MB   | #########################################################################1                                                        |  57% python-3.8.5         | 49.3 MB   | #########################################################################7                                                        |  57% 

CondaSignalInterrupt: Signal interrupt SIGINT
```

It downloaded python-3.8.5, which should not happen since I already have it on my base environment. However, if I tried:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml --offline
```

It results on:

```
usage: conda-env [-h] {create,export,list,remove,update,config} ...
conda-env: error: unrecognized arguments: --offline
```

After I read the manual, there is no `--use-index-cache` either. Currently I found a way to work around this by removing and creating the environment again. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: When I run `conda env update -h`, I see no options which would allow for offline installation.

Comment: @AMC exactly. My usecase is to reflect the changes on environment.yml into the actual environment without removing and adding the environment back.

Comment: It may not be possible, unfortunately.

Comment: @AMC is there any alternative to this?